# Systemd: Start operation timed out. Terminating

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, systemd, flask-socketio

I'm trying to create an autostart service for my python-flask-socketio server.

I need to start a python script through systemd. Here's my service code:

```
[Unit]
Description=AppName


[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /opt/myapp/app.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I try to start it manually using `sudo service myservice start` - it works just fine. It halts my terminal\ssh window but I can close it and it works like expected.

But when I reboot my PC it does not start. When checking it's status with `systemctl status myservice` I get the following:

```
systemd[1]: Starting My Service...
systemd[1]: myserivce.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
systemd[1]: Failed to start My Service.
systemd[1]: myserivce.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: myserivce.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: But I saw a lot of similar questions that were not down voted... Why is that? I humbly ask for explanation. I'd like  to delete this question to fix the problem, as it can not be rephrased. But I can't do this.

Comment: Stack Overflow does a poor job of policing itself. Many off-topic questions pass without incident. Its a big disservice because its like a trap for folks who come later. If the question does not pass the high level sniff test of, *is it a programming or development question*, then it probably does not belong here. How to run a program as a service or how to configure systemd does not pass the sniff test. I eat my own dog food. Here's my latest systemd question on U&L.SE: [Fedora 26 and fully qualified domain names?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/378390/56041). It was asked today.

Comment: As for *Deletion* and *Migration*... You can flag the question and ask the moderators move it so you don't have to delete it on one site and create it on another site. For whatever reasons, the Stack Exchange network does not allow you to migrate it yourself. Also see [Author initiated migration to other SE sites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Comment: this -1 killed my reputation and I am not sure what I can do to get out of this ban.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your type seems wrong, forking is for programs that detach immediately by themselves. Flask does not, it stays attached to your console.

Your service type should probably be `simple`

Comment: Well that's weird, I'm sure I tried simple and it did not work. But it does now. Well, I guess I tried it in my sleep :D

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Set a larger start timeout:

```
[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=300
```

In case your service would actually need more time to complete the startup.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check /var/log/message.

After you start service, If your script works normally at first and then failed, try this.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/python3 /opt/myapp/app.py'
```

Answer (score -4):

It really took me one hour to figure this out :o

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33218285)